# C# if statement with multiple statements not equal != not working

Tags: c#

C# I am trying to evaluate using a if statement to "do something" if the text inside a comboBox.text is not equal to "textexample" or "textexample2" multiple times but i cant manage to make it work help please.  c# beginner

The statement work if its used 1 time but not if its used 2 or more.

```
if (comboBox10.Text =="" || comboBox11.Text =="" || comboBox12.Text == "")
{
   if (comboBox1.Text != "desk" || comboBox1.Text != "table" || comboBox1.Text != "chair")
   {
     MessageBox.Show("something", "Error!", MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
     connection.Close();
     return;
   }
}
```

the program is ignoring completely !=

Comment: Bro... Change the logical OR to logical AND...In the second If block..

Comment: Think about your logic on your inner if statement. If it doesn't equal desk or doesn't equal table or it doesn't equal chair, it will go into that if statement. Therefore, it will always go into that block. You probably && instead of ||. This is just basic logic - stop and think about exactly what you're writing means.

Comment: Please explain "... but not if used 2 or more." What results are you getting? Have you traced this through the debugger?

Comment: **[Using the free, built-in Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)** is easier than you think and reveals many Mysteries of How Your Code Works

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the AND operator instead of OR. As soon as one of the != statements is satisfied, it will enter the if statement's code block. Meaning if the comboBox1.Text== "table", the code will check it against "desk" and the if statement will be satisfied and never check to see if it doesn't equal "table".

The line should read:

```
if (comboBox1.Text != "desk" && comboBox1.Text != "table" && comboBox1.Text != "chair")
```

This will make sure it doesn't equal ANY of those strings

Comment: You mean the && operator.

Comment: Yeah my bad was writing in short hand and not thinking about how confusing it may be to say & instead of the word "and". Was editing it as your comment popped up :D

Answer (score 1):

Use AND `&&` not OR `||`.

When you want to check that a value is *not* one of *many* possible values, use the AND operator with NOT equal.

Consider the case where `comboBox1.Text = "desk"`.

```
comboBox1.Text != "desk"   // => false
comboBox1.Text != "table"  // => true
comboBox1.Text != "chair"  // => true
```

therefore, your `if` statement will always evaluate to true if you use OR:

```
false OR true OR true => true
```

Changing to AND would result in:

```
false && true && true => false
```

which evaluates to false, as expected.

You may want to refer to the Wikipedia articles [negation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation) and [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).